# predict_proba version issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to get probability of each class in the following code,

```
# example making new probability predictions for a classification problem
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# generate 2d classification dataset
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=2, n_features=2, random_state=1)
scalar = MinMaxScaler()
scalar.fit(X)
X = scalar.transform(X)
# define and fit the final model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, verbose=0)
# new instances where we do not know the answer
Xnew, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=3, centers=2, n_features=2, random_state=1)
Xnew = scalar.transform(Xnew)
# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict_proba(Xnew)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
for i in range(len(Xnew)):
    print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[i], ynew[i]))
```

However, I am getting the following error,

`AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'`

I was running this before so I assume this is a version issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: may I know the source for `model.predict_proba`, i don't think keras model has this `predict_proba` method.

Comment: You don't need predict_proba, predict will work fine.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I thought predict is just for predicting classes not probabilities

Comment: No, predicts only gives you the output of the model, it does not do any postprocessing.

Comment: @simpleApp https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-make-classification-and-regression-predictions-for-deep-learning-models-in-keras/

Comment: i think that site is not current, you can use this `ynew = model.predict(Xnew)`, your output layer activation is `sigmoid` so it will be probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

`predict_proba()` is deprectaed and no longer in use, hence showing the above error. You can use `predict()`instead to get the model probabilities.

Please do changes as below:

```
# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)  #<----
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
for i in range(len(Xnew)):
    print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[i], ynew[i]))
```

Output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 97ms/step
X=[0.89337759 0.65864154], Predicted=[0.00160966]
X=[0.29097707 0.12978982], Predicted=[0.9925072]
X=[0.78082614 0.75391697], Predicted=[0.00363357]
```